# fullcalendar two days event span days are displaying in only one day

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I wany to display full calendar monthly view events in different dates if event is overnight booking.

I am not getting any idea about this topic as it was customized to display events in single days and its not supporting drag option.

We are passing string as text to display content.

My Javascript integration code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
     dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        if (allDay) {
            // Clicked on the entire day
            convertedDate= convert(date);
            if ($(jsEvent.target).is('span.fc-day-content') ){
                // Clicked on the day number
                      if(${managePriv ==1}){
                          var selectedDate = document.getElementById("selectedDate").value;
                          window.open("<%=contextPath%>/rooms/roomReservationFrame.action?startingtime="+convertedDate+"&screenFlag=M&selectedDate="+selectedDate,"roomReservation","width=840,height=460,scrollBars=no");
                      }
            }
        } 
    }, 
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: '',
        right: ''
    },
    events: ${jsonstring} ,

    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
        element.find('span.fc-event-title').html(element.find('span.fc-event-title').text());
         if (event.start.getMonth() != view.start.getMonth())
            return false; 
    }

});
var date = new Date();
var d = 1;
var m="${month}";
var y="${year}";
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', y,m,d);

    if(${managePriv !=1}){
      $('span.fc-day-content').css({'visibility': 'hidden'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here issue is for every json object we have to add color:'colorcode' attribute , as it is displaying but default its showing white background show its showing in only in one day and div class = 'fc-event-title' i am appending text directly to that div , so its just printing label like plain text.need any clarification for this question replay back me

Comment: What you want is, need to set your own html in the title, right?

Comment: yes , I wanted to do the same , sorry for late I had fixed this one.and there in my json string they are ovverriding color code so , even though overlapped data is displaying in background i am not able to see that one because of my json string color is overriding not to display content . now i have modified my json string and its color codes.